# Даны 2 текстовых файла. Верно ли, что они состоят из одних и тех же строк (но, возможно, строки идут в разном порядке)

Tags: python, java, c#, c++, pascal

Даны 2 текстовых файла. Верно ли, что они состоят из одних и тех же строк (но, возможно, строки идут в разном порядке).

Я не понял суть вопроса. Можете объяснить пример. Или любой язык программирования. Только без использования linq.

Comment: Не надо спамить языковыми тегами. Указывайте всегда один предпочитаемый. А то вам здесь код могут и на Brainfuck написать подумав, что вам всё равно.

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь, человек хотел на c#, но ему дали ответы на других языках )

Comment: @АлексейОбухов Человек написал в тэгах тучу разных языков, поэтому и получил ответы на чём угодно )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно ли перестановкой строк получить из одного файла второй. Например

```
     I                             II
Hello, world!              To be or not to be?
I don't understand         Hello, world!
To be or not to be?        I don't understand
```

Вот пример — набор строк одинаков ("они состоят из одних и тех же строк, но, возможно, в разном порядке").

```
     I                             II
Hello, world!              To be!
I don't understand         Hello, world!
To be or not to be?        I don't understand
```

А вот тут - нет: Строки `To be or not to be?` нет во втором файле, `To be!` — в первом.

Проверить... Можно по-разному, но, пожалуй, лучше всего отсортировать строки одного файла и второго, и сравнивать по одной.

Конечно, как минимум, перед этим можно убедиться, что размеры файлов равны — иначе они a priori отличаются.

Я внятно пояснил суть задачи? Как именно сортировать — вопрос второй, зависит от размера файлов, например, от количества строк и т.д.

P.S. А, да! раз язык программирования любой... Командный интерпретатор Windows:

```
@echo off
sort %1 > %1.~~~
sort %2 > %2.~~~
fc %1.~~~ %2.~~~ > nul
if errorlevel 1 (
echo Fail
) else (
echo OK
)
del %1.~~~
del %2.~~~
```

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо..... Я почти забыл командный интерпретатор windows.  Я попробую написать под c#)))

Answer (score 2):

Читаем оба в файла в словари вида `<строка>: <счётчик>`. Если словари одинаковы то и наборы строк в файлах одинаковы:

```
import collections
import sys

c1, c2 = (collections.Counter(open(fname)) for fname in sys.argv[1:])
sys.exit(0 if c1 == c2 else 1)
```

> ```
> $ cat a.txt 
> 0
> 1
> 2
>
> $ cat b.txt 
> 1
> 2
> 0
>
> $ cat c.txt 
> 0
> 2
> 3
>
> $ python cmp.py a.txt b.txt && echo Yes || echo No
> Yes
>
> $ python cmp.py a.txt c.txt && echo Yes || echo No
> No
> ```

Comment: Одна строка это хорошо, но `open` без `with` или без `close` как-то не очень, наверное :)

Comment: В данном случае мне не интересно когда файлы будут закрыты. Никаких лишних ресурсов они не потребляют. В общем случае я всегда использую `with`. Тут мне нужно было оставить BAT за флагом.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что Python при этом затянет в память оба файла полностью? Если нет — умолкаю, в Python я не спец. Но если да, то если файлы размером несколько гигабайт, это не лучший вариант... Тогда лучше ограничиться чтением в память одного файла, а второго — построчно с проверкой наличия строки.

Comment: @Harry Сами файлы будут читаться построчно, но в памяти будет словарь из уникальных строк и счётчиков их повторений. Для каждого из файлов. Так что да, если файлы большие и строки там не сильно повторяются, то можно сказать, что файлы целиком будут сидеть в памяти.

Comment: @Harry, вы правы, оба словаря будут в памяти. Можно обойтись одним словарём. В принципе есть алгоритмы со словарями для внешней памяти. Но не думаю что ни будут лучше сортировки.